# a stupid 'important' question about php $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have 2 files that put something in the $_SESSION array.
file1.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION[] = 'Hi';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

That prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hi
)
```

And file2.php that is similar to file1

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION[] = 'There!';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

I suppose to go to file1 at first and then move to file2.
Printing $_SESSION in file2 should output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hi
    [1] => There!
)
```

am I wrong?

I've to mention that I get the notice: Unknown skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0.
And the register_globals in my php.ini is set to Off.

As I see in the comments for someone of you file2 prints an array of 2 items and for someone else (like me) the 'hi' items get lost. This seems to happen, but not for Marc B, only if we use a number  as index of the session array, not with a string.

For Marc B the session behaves as I expected. Can you post your php.ini here? So I can compare yours with mine?

Comment: The best teacher is experience.  This is a simply enough question you could just try it...

Comment: well, of course I tested it :) but, as I get in file2 only Array([0]=>There!). I started to doubt about the way I use this array. Normally if I define an array $a=array() then I can add items by doing a[]=0;a[]='Hello'..., but it seems it's not the same for the $_SESSION array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Superglobals like `$_SESSION` are not normal arrays. You should store an array inside `$_SESSION`, like so:

file 1: `$_SESSION['foo'][] = 'Hi!';`

file 2: `$_SESSION['foo'][] = 'there';`

Comment: Yes, They are different from normal arrays. I didn't know that... maybe because I used that in a more complex way (array of array...).
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't giving `$_SESSION` the appropriate key.

Answer (score 0):

No, that should work. In fact, if you just kept reloading file1, you'd just get a series of "Hi", "Hi", "Hi", etc.. array entries.

Comment: If I reload file1.php I get everytime Array([0] => Hi). I'm wondering why

Comment: 0 will remain Hi until the session is lost, look at 1,2,3 print_r($_SESSION)

Comment: If all you're getting is the one entry, then your session isn't being preserved across requests. Check that the session cookie is properly going server->you->server between each page request. If you get a different session ID each time, then it's a new blank session, which explains why there's only the one "Hi"

Comment: It's exactely what I experienced. The session file on the system is blank. But I think it's not the way it's supposed to be. Maybe something wrong in the php.ini? I googled for something similar and I found something about register_globals which is set to Off in my environment

Comment: register_globals should always be off. it's a hideous idea, major security hole, and will be removed in future php versions. If your session file's blank, then something's not right your cookie setup, and you're creating a new session each time.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you did

```
$_SESSION[]='Hi' instead of $_SESSION["Greet"]='Hi'?
```

I have tested your code. when i started file1.php i have the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hi
)
```

with the following notice: Unknown skipping numeric key 0 in **Unknown** on line 0
and after that i went on to file2.php i have the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => there!
)
```

with the same notice. simply put to answer your question you are wrong :).
If you added the indexes ("greet" and "meet" respectively) to the session variable this would be the output on page 1:

```
Array
(
   [greet]=> hi      
)
```

and when you go on file2.php you would have:

```
Array
(
  [greet] => hi
  [meet] => there!
)
```

Comment: It's just an example I made because I got a weird behaviour of the session

Answer (score -1):

file1:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['0'] = 'Hi';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

That prints 
Array
(
    [0] => Hi
)
```

And file2.php that is similar to file1 but different session index

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['1'] = 'There!';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

Now this prints 
Array
(
    [0] => Hi
    [1] => There!
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work :( It seems that if I use numeric indexes such as 0,1 or even '0','1' the session is not preserved. while if I use index like 'zero','one' the things seem to work. Any ideas?